# Jetty 7 web.xml configuration for Spring web 3.0.5

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jetty, web.xml

I configured a Jetty 7 embedded mode in eclipse indigo. When i start jetty in eclipse it seems not loading my web.xml and spring-servlet.xml configuration. I search on the net, it seems everybody doing the same configuration as me but mine doesn't load. Did i forgot something ? or Jetty 7 configuration its different than jetty 6 ?

Main.java

```
  Server server = new Server(8080);

  WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
  context.setResourceBase("../jettyserver/webapp");
  context.setContextPath("/");
  context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

  HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
  handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{ context, new DefaultHandler()});

  server.setHandler(context);
  try {
         server.start();
     server.join();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

web.xml

```
 <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:annotation-config />
     <context:component-scan base-package="com.jetty.controller" />

     <bean id="viewResolver"
       class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
       <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
 </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert here but if you are using eclipse I'd say there could be a problem with your resource base.

Depending on how you use Eclipse here (WTP, Maven etc) the compiled code will end up in the target folder somewhere.  However your JSP and all may not follow or may not be where you'd think they are.

Compile your code and look in your target folder see where it is.  I do something similar but it's testing code so I don't really care if the paths are linked to my IDE.  our versions are pretty much identical, applicative differences aside, except for these :

```
    WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
    webapp.setDescriptor("target/app/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    webapp.setResourceBase("target/app");
    webapp.setContextPath("/app");
```

As you can see here the root path of the application run-time within Eclipse is your project's root path in your workspace.  I set mine so it finds it's stuff relative to the project's root path, hence the target in there.

If however you are looking for code that runs in both your environment and once deployed you could probably change the root folder in the run configuration for your particular application and set it to target directly (or whatever works for you).

Sorry for not being more decisive here,

Anyways, hope this helps.